# How do I convert my dataframe to something I can make a network visualisation of in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, networking, igraph

I have a dataframe in R where each row is a song, and each column is an artist that collaborates on the song. I want to visualise which artists work together. I'm figuring I could do some kind of network analysis, but I don't know how to convert my dataframe to a network, or something with nodes and edges, or a vertex.

```
song <- c('You','Strings','Club','Never','Yolo','Do it','Again','The world', 'Forever')
artist1 <- c('Art', 'Bee', 'Con', 'Con', 'Dev', 'Art', 'Evi', 'Evi', 'Guy')
artist2 <- c('Bee', 'Evi', NA, 'Bee', 'Fay', 'Con', 'Bee', 'Dev', NA)
artist3 <- c('Con', 'Fay', NA, NA, NA, 'Bee', 'Art', 'Con', NA)
df <- data.frame(song, artist1, artist2, artist3)
```

What I guess I need to count (and then visualise) is how often each artist occurs in the same row as each other artist. The network would then show the artists as nodes and the collaborations (weighted) as edges.

Any clues as to how to go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adjacency matrix with `crossprod`, then use `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` to create a graph object, and then plot it:

```r
ta <- crossprod(table(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1]))[-3]))

graph_from_adjacency_matrix(ta, diag = F, weighted = T, mode = "undirected") %>% 
  plot(edge.width = E(.)$weight)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! In reality, I have 11 columns with artists. I first tried to change stack(df[-1]))[-3]) to stack(df[-1]))[-11]), but that gave an error. If I keep the code as is, it seems to work. Can you explain why?

Comment: Look at the output of `cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1]))`. We're removing the third column of that object, which does not depend on the number of columns in the original data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(!song, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    select(!name) %>%
    rev() %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% df$song) %>%
    plot(layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is OP's expected result. OP needs the collaborations between artists

Comment: @Maël Yes, I think you are right, it seems I misundersood the goal. Upvoted yours :)